# Count string value?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Hey, Im a newbie in cocoa and I have a string and I am trying to count how long it is.  I have been searching through Apples docs but I can't find anything.

NSString *word = @"word";

How would I figure out how many characters is in a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[word length];
```